# cancelled stamp in passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, senegal, ghana

My problem is that 2 months ago i wanted to travel from Ghana to Senegal but forgot my invitation letter. Senegal immigration would not admit me without an invitation letter, Now I'm back but Ghana put a cancelled stamp in my passport (but exit or entry date cancelled). In 2 days I'm going to travel to Senegal again with the invitation letter and pass freely, so my question is, if I seek entry in another Country, will they accept my passport?

Comment: Welcome! I'm confused. What country are you a citizen of? Did they cancel your passport or a visa inside your passport? Are you saying that Ghana cancel your passport because Senegal wouldn't let you in?

Comment: @ZachLipton My qualified guess is they cancelled his Exit stamp. Also he's unlikely to be Ghanaian. There are nationalities that require **either** a visa **or** an Invitation letter, but Ghana is completely visa-free for max 90 days

Comment: Please reply with the country of issuance of your passport and where was the canceled stamp stamped? I am assuming they just canceled your current visa for Ghana; that's right?

Comment: I m from Singapore and I live in Ghana I m doing business so my visa is not cancelled just exit or entry date if I apply any so no problem for visa

Comment: @AliAli If you're a Singaporean citizen, then you've been a victim of corruption. Singaporeans can enter Senegal without a visa or invitation letter for tourism or Business, for max 90 days. They probably expected you to bribe them, and when you ddn't refused you entry. A depressingly common phenomenon in Africa :(

Comment: OK but question is my passport valid or not but I have stamp

Comment: And visa is not cancelled just enter and exit stamp

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, countries try to welcome *genuine* tourists and business travelers and to refuse entry to *illegal* immigrants.

To make the decision, they look at your documents and their databases, if they have any data on you. They also ask you. A history of travel for legitimate reasons and without overstay incident is good. A previous visa or entry refusal is bad. Being caught in a lie is even worse.

So there is a good chance that the visa officials will note your refusal of entry. But a place like the EU or US won't give too much weight to a stamp from Senegal, and it won't be the **only** reason for their decision.

Comment: My brother I like your comments and now I have no problem about cancelled stamp if I apply any country so no problem